# CKEditor won't load php variable

Tags: php, html, textarea, ckeditor

i've added a textarea control in my PHP page, using the CKEditor's class.
Now if the textarea loads empty, CKEditor works. But if i try to load a PHP variable in the textarea, the page show correctly the editor, but it won't show the content (and the editor appears to be blocked).
Here's my code:

```
<div id="dialog-edit" title="Edit" style="display: none;">
    <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                <form method="post" name="form">
                <tr>
                        <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>                    
                <br/>
                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="html" id="html" style="width: 766px; height: 390px; margin-left: 6px;"><?php echo htmlentities($html) ?></textarea><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Salva modifiche" class="button" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialogEdit()
    {
        $( "#dialog-edit" ).dialog({

                width: 680,
                height: 620,
                modal: true,
                open: function(event, ui)
                {

                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

The textarea must show the content (saved in a MySQL database as an HTML code), into the textarea, but it isn't doing this.
What's making this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $html;`  instead of `print $html;` ? And are you sure about the value of `$html` ?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M yes, and it isn't still working...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the value of `$html` is empty. Can you echo it somewhere else and see is it empty or not?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M the value of $html isn't empty because the same value is viewed above the editor.

Comment: Is the content of `$html` properly escaped, or does it contain HTML tags? Try `<?php echo htmlentities($html) ?>` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger $html contains HTML tags, and the htmlentities isn't still working...

Comment: Any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Blazemonger there isn't any JavaScript errors... but it's possible that a Jquery Dialog (where's located the editor), causes an issue?

Comment: Without a more complete sample of your code, it's impossible to say. Please post more code and/or create a functional example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Blazemonger I've added a part of the source code. I hope this will help you :-)

Comment: In your HTML, that opening `<form>` tag should go before the `<table>` tag that follows it to maintain proper nesting. Otherwise the browser may close your form for you before the textarea. Sadly, even with that change, [I can't reproduce your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/g2HFn/).

Comment: @Blazemonger my issue is not depending by the <form> tag, I've tried... however, my <textarea> shows the content if I delete the class="ckeditor", but the <textarea> shows the html code as it is, and not the html interpreted, I need the class="ckeditor", but with this property, the <textarea> won't show the content...

Comment: I wonder if jQueryUI is somehow stripping the CKeditor functionality when it opens the dialog. What happens if you move the CKeditor-initialization code inside of the Dialog open event handler?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/g2HFn/3/ -- still no problems. However, let me know if following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/g2HFn/4/) works -- it uses the jQueryUI Dialog "open" event to trigger CKEditor without the "ckeditor" class.

Comment: @FrancescoSorge If Blazemonger's answer solved the problem, please accept the answer. It gives credit for the effort and tells people who are searching about a similar problem that a helpful answer was given for your question.

Comment: @codewaggle sure, I've done this now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following the "replace by code" example in the CKEditor demo folder instead:

1. Remove the "ckeditor" class from the textarea.
2. Modify the the jQueryUI dialog "open" event to trigger it *after* the dialog is opened.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/g2HFn/4/

```
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
    width: 680,
    height: 620,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        CKEDITOR.replace('html');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write in config file of ckeditor (config.js)

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    /* ALLOW <?php ... ?> tags */
    config.protectedSource.push(/<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g); 
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'style';
};
```